# Windows 8 (not pro) - printer removal

Tags: windows-8, printer

Friend of mine bought a Samsung All-In-One PC with Windows 8 (not pro). He added an HP Photosmart printer and it was working for a day or two then stopped. So I logged in and checked all settings. Couldn't get it to work. So I removed the printer and re-installed it. In Control Panel -> Printers, it only shows his HP printer that I installed. The one I removed is still gone.

However, opening Microsoft Word or any other application, still shows the old printer there with 3 items in print queue. How can I remove this reference?

There isn't a print management snap-in available in the non-pro version.

Comment: Has the PC has been rebooted since the printer un-installation?

Comment: Yes, it has been rebooted. All Windows updates are completed.

Comment: The process to remove the printer would be exactly the same.  The fact its Windows 8 vs Windows 8 Professional makes no difference in a case like this.  I have no idea what the "print management snap-in" is exactly provide a screenshot of it.

Comment: Not sure how to post a snap-shot. However, if you have Win 7 pro or Win 8 pro, you can go to control panel -> administrative tools -> print management. It gives you options to delete just the printer, or printer with driver, and other settings.

Comment: Take a snap shot and then hit the **edit** button and then press **Ctrl+G** and then post the screen shot here.

Comment: @Markaway - My parent's home premium copy of Windows 7 has those options so its not limited to professional versions of Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Since your printer spooler queue is still containing items, resetting that might do the trick.

Do the following to reset your print spooler queue.

1. Open a command window (<kbd>winkey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) and execute `net stop spooler`
2. Execute `del /F /Q C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*`
3. Execute `net start spooler`

If this happens on a regular basis, you can easily put the three command lines in a batch file (save a new text file as ResetSpooler.bat) that you can run from the desktop or some other convenient place.

Comment: I'll give that a shot as well when I get a chance to get to the computer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try CCleaner and see if this removes it

Make sure that no reference to the old printer remains in control panel.

Open Devices and click on any printer (the HP will be fine) and then click **Print Server Properties** which appears as a 'tab' in at the top of the window (see screen shot).

[image]

Open the printer properties and the click the drivers tab. From here, select the old printers and click Remove. Repeat for each printer you want to remove.

Comment: I'll give that a shot in a bit. Trying to figure out why LogMeIn won't let me connect all of a sudden.

Comment: Only one HP driver is shown.

Comment: And did you try ccleaner? And check the Programs and Features to see if anything still exists?

Comment: Couldn't get CCleaner installed because LogMeIn kicked me off again. I think their home connection is slow and can't handle me being connected while other Internet activity is occuring. I'll have to make a trip out seems like. I'll post a follow up if anything gets resolved.