# Print job stuck in Word 2013 for printer that has been deleted

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

When I look at printing a document withing MS Word 2013 I can see that there is a printer which is no longer installed on the computer listed which says:

"Paused - Delete: 1 document waiting"

Since the printer no longer exists I can't figure out how to remove that printer from the printer options within Word. I've tried rebooting and restarting the print spooler without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: "printer which is no longer installed" and "the printer no longer exists". Do you mean to say that the printer is physically gone *and* the printer driver software has been uninstalled?

Comment: What OS? Home situation, network?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/529354/windows-8-not-pro-printer-removal

Comment: I've had similar, you have to first cancel all print jobs (if possible on on your OS) and then you can delete it fully. You may also need to remove it as a device and even remove the driver.

Comment: @JanDoggen Yes, the printer is removed from the client system fully. It is not present under Printers/Devices at all. The only trace is in MS Word.

Comment: @JanDoggen Thanks for pointing out the possible duplicate. However, it should be noted that there is no accepted answer to that question so there is still value to this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to the folder that contains the `Printer Spool` file(s) and delete them.

The file(s) you need to be looking at should exist in the following directory:

`C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS`

Deleting the file(s) from the above folder should remove the Print Job. However, I'm not sure if it will remove the entry from `Word 2013`.

Comment: I ended up doing this in a slightly different way but this is the same end result so I'll accept this answer. I ended up following the (not accepted) answer over here which has you do the same thing via CLI: http://superuser.com/questions/529354/windows-8-not-pro-printer-removal

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me, in Windows 8.1, was opening a Command Line window **as an administrator**, then running:

```
net stop spooler
delete C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*.*
net start spooler
```

Welcome to the joys of user-friendliness in 2015, folks !